# How to query multiple weak tables using a join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with two strong entities, and three weak entities. The weak entities only have foreign key references to the primary key of the strong tables they related to, to create an association between the tables.

I have a query selecting from one table the way I want, but am not sure how to go about selecting from all three tables at once and displaying the data in one query.

**ERD:**

[image]

I have tried many different joins and can not get them to work properly. This select displays the information that I want for one table:

```
select f.FilmName, concat(p.FirstName, ' ', p.LastName) as Producer
from filmtable as f
inner join persontable as p
inner join produced;
```

I would like to be able to select and display all the information from all three weak tables, in a format similar to:

FilmName, Producer, ScreenWriter, Director.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

```
select f.FilmName, concat(ppr.FirstName, ' ', ppr.LastName) as Producer,
concat(psw.FirstName, ' ', psw.LastName) as ScreenWriter,
concat(pdir.FirstName, ' ', pdir.LastName) as Director
from filmtable as f
left join produced as prod ON prod.FilmID = f.FilmID
left join Directed as dir ON dir.FilmID = f.FilmID
left join ScreenWote as sw ON sw.FilmID = f.FilmID
left join persontable as ppr ON prod.PersonID = ppr.personID
left join persontable as psw ON sw.PersonID = psw.personID
left join persontable as pdir ON dir.PersonID = pdir.personID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution is to use `sub queries` in `SELECT` statement to achieve all 3 parties i.e. Producer, Writer and Director, in one row.

```
SELECT f.FilmName,
    (
        SELECT concat(p.FirstName, ' ', p.LastName)
        FROM persontable AS pt
        JOIN produced AS a
        ON pt.PersonID = a.PersonID
        WHERE p.FilmID = f.FilmID
   ) AS producer,
   (
       SELECT concat(p.FirstName, ' ', p.LastName)
       FROM persontable AS pt
       JOIN screenwrote AS a
       ON pt.PersonID = a.PersonID
       WHERE p.FilmID = f.FilmID
   ) AS ScreenWriter,
   (
       SELECT concat(p.FirstName, ' ', p.LastName)
       FROM persontable AS pt
       JOIN directed AS a
       ON pt.PersonID = a.PersonID
       WHERE p.FilmID = f.FilmID
   ) AS Director

FROM filmtable AS f
```